# Spring JDBC Exceptions

Tags: spring, jdbc

```
My spring.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crunchify.*" />
    <bean id="Circle" class="com.crunchify.bean.Circle" autowire="byName">
        <property name="point">
            <value>100</value>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CircleDao" class="com.crunchify.dao.CircleDao" autowire="byName">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jdbcTemplateObject" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/xe" />
        <property name="username" value="rohith" />
        <property name="password" value="rohithrohith" />
    </bean>



</beans>


DAO CLass
package com.crunchify.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import com.crunchify.bean.Circle;

public class CircleDao {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;

    }

    public void create(String name, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age);
        System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
        return;
    }

    public void delete(Integer id) {
        String SQL = "delete from Student where id = ?";
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
        System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id);
        return;
    }

    public void update(Integer id, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "update Student set age = ? where id = ?";
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, age, id);
        System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id);
        return;
    }

    public int getDataFromDataBase() {

        int resutlCount = 0;
        String sql = "select count(*) from CIRCLE";
        jdbcTemplateObject.execute(sql);
        return resutlCount;
    }

}


package com.crunchify.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.crunchify.bean.Circle;
import com.crunchify.dao.CircleDao;
import com.crunchify.dao.SpringDao;

/*
 * author: Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Circle cir = (Circle) context.getBean("Circle");
        int point = cir.getPoint();
        System.out.println("point" + point);
        SpringDao nn = (SpringDao) context.getBean("SpringDao");
        int res = nn.getDataFromDataBase();
        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome2")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld2() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Raja Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome2", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Forms")
    public String Form(@ModelAttribute("point") Circle student, ModelMap model) {
        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Raja Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        System.out.println("SSS" + student.getPoint());
        model.addAttribute("point", student.getPoint());
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        CircleDao nn = (CircleDao) context.getBean("CircleDao");
        System.out.println("DERED");
        int res = nn.getDataFromDataBase();
        return "result";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView Form() {
        System.out.println("HIII");
        return new ModelAndView("Forms", "command", new Circle());
    }
}


getting following exception

Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringExample' did not find a matching property.
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 15 2016 16:27:45 UTC
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.70.0
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b15
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\rohithsree\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Windows.old.000\Users\RohithSree\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.70
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:54519
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\rohithsree\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Windows.old.000\Users\RohithSree\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.70
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\rohithsree\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Windows.old.000\Users\RohithSree\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\endorsed
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Users\rohithsree\Downloads\Eclipse Mars R\jee\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 875 ms
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'crunchify'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'crunchify': initialization started
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'crunchify-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 31 10:23:11 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:11 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/crunchify-servlet.xml]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Forms] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Forms.*] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Forms/] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Form] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Form.*] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Form/] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome.*] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome/] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome2] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome2.*] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome2/] onto handler 'crunchifyHelloWorld'
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:13 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'crunchify': initialization completed in 1291 ms
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3316 ms
HIII
HIII
SSS0
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:29 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ac70e58: startup date [Wed Aug 31 10:23:29 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:29 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:29 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
Aug 31, 2016 10:23:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [crunchify] in context with path [/CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.crunchify.controller.CrunchifyHelloWorld.Form(CrunchifyHelloWorld.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:454)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:147)
    ... 69 more
```

I would like connect to the Database add get some result..that's it
As I'm new to spring it is simple code..please help me to figure out the problem.

Please let me know how to correct this problem..

I was reading the spring.xml and then once the beans are instantiated would like to call the DAO method but here the Beans are not being instantiated which is causing this issue..

Answer (score 0):

It says `Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]` which means you don't have the JDBC jar on your class path.

If you're using Maven, please note Oracle no longer publish their JDBC to public Maven repos anymore. You'll have to manually download one from their website.

Comment: Do I need to follow these steps?????https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc

Comment: Please update the questipn with how you defined the datasource in spring xml?

Comment: ojdbc6 should do. Do you have a new exception now?

Comment: @notionquest i have sprinh.xml definition in the post.. 
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
  autowire="byName">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/xe" />
  <property name="username" value="rohith" />
  <property name="password" value="rohithrohith" />
 </bean>

Comment: @billc.cn.. the same exception stack trace

Comment: The setup should work. How did you supply the JDBC jar to the JVM?

Comment: hey i solved it by uing mysql & Sql jar's..or some reason oracl drivers are not working..